# "empty String" when parse json into model class in android with kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I am Android developer,

I am facing a problem while making an API call.

I am receiving a huge amount of data, making an API call, and I get the API call success, I can see the JSON response in the logcat.

Now I convert that JSON response to a model class. Then I faced a problem. I get an exception something like this. "empty String".

But my data is huge. I can't find where exactly the problem is.

#### Here is what I use

- `Retrofit` - for API call
- `Gson` - for converting and handling data

#### What have I tried?

```kotlin
ActivitiesApiRepository.searchActivities(object : retrofit2.Callback<JsonElement> {
    //...
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<JsonElement>, response: Response<JsonElement>) {
        val mResponse = Gson().fromJson(response.body(), MyModelClass::class.java)
    }
}
```

- Second try

```kotlin
ActivitiesApiRepository.searchActivities(object : retrofit2.Callback<MyModelClass> {
    //...
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<MyModelClass>, response: Response<MyModelClass>) {
        val mResponse = response.body() as MyModelClass
    }
}
```

###### Every time I got the same exception `empty String`

Please any have solution how can I manage it?

Comment: `Please any have solution how can I manage it?` your problem isn't the parsing, the problem is that you don't know how to debug the app. do you have a stack trace ? have you read it ? does it point you somewhere ?

Comment: Can you write json response and your MyModelClass data class?

Comment: There is a plugin called JSON to Kotlin data class. Try using it to convert the Json Data to kotlin class. It makes the values nullable by default so it helps a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurred when your model class does not match your raw json result
normally. I guess a variable type is "empty string" on your raw json result, and "List type" or "custom class type" on your code. You can copy and paste your json result to the text editor and try formatting it, and you can see the formatted result. Focus on the empty string result, and verify in your code whether it's the correct type.